# Kotlin problem with billing library when no inapp purchase

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

when i wanted to release my app on google play store console, i got and error : "`We've detected that this app uses an unsupported version of Play Billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app.`"
But i don't understand because i have no billing library because my application doesn't have Inapp Purchase. Here are my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.poovam:pin-edittext-field:1.1.2'

    /**
     * SUPPORT
     */
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    /**
     * GSON
     */
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    /**
     * IMAGE LOADING/CACHING/EDITING LIBS
     */
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'

    /**
     * FastAdapter
     */
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-commons:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:3.3.1'
    implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'

    /**
     * CAROUSEL
     */
    implementation 'com.github.devlight:infinitecycleviewpager:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.chauthai.overscroll:overscroll-bouncy:0.1.1'

    /**
     * RX JAVA x RX BINDING
     */
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.7"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.2.0"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-kotlin:2.2.0"

    /**
     * GroupieAdapter
     */
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.xwray:groupie:2.7.0"
    implementation "com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.7.0"
    implementation "com.xwray:groupie-databinding:2.7.0"


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2")

    /**
     * Flurry
     */
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:12.4.0@aar'
}
```

So i was wondering do we need to implement billing library even if we don't have Inapp Purchase? or does it come from one of my library have requires it?

Comment: Do you have a billing AIDL file in your path? Also, why are you declaring old support library dependencies in combination with Jetpack? Seems like that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: So i don't have any billing AIDL file, and i just got an old project with outated library, i am working to update it little by little.